# run django related script in crontab

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, cron

Hi in my local python interpreter I run `./manage.py shell < slack_application/slack_notifications.py` in my activated venv and everything works...

How can I do the same via a crontab that should work on my ubuntu server?

I am trying:

```
cd Django django_env/bin/activate ./manage.py shell < slack_application/slack_notifications.py)
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: I just figured it out

Comment: ```* * * * * cd Django && django_env/bin/python ./manage.py shell < slack_application/slack_notifications.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Tries to reach your venv python interpreter with absolute path:

```sh
0 4 * * * /absolute/path/to/django_env/bin/python /absolute/path/to/manage.py <some commands>
```

Or tries to activate it and the run your command:

```sh
0 4 * * * /absolute/path/to/django_env/bin/activate; python /absolute/path/to/manage.py <some commands>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

```
* * * * * cd Django && django_env/bin/python ./manage.py shell < slack_application/slack_notifications.py
```